# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type after bytecode instrumentation

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I instrumented some Java bytecode. What I try to do is this:

```
InstrumentStackElem[] stack;
int stackpointer;
void foo(){
    stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % stack.length;
    InstrumentStackElem localref = stack[stackpointer];
    localref.init();

    //before each return
    localref.clear();
    stackpointer = (stackpointer -1 +stack.length) % stack.length;
```

So at the beginning of each method I increment the stackpointer and grab a local reference to the array element. Before each return, I call a clear method on the element and decrease the counter again.

When I try to access the field for the call of localref.clear() I always get a java.lang.VerifyError.

Example method:

```
public static boolean isValidName(final String s) {
        if (!s.matches("[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*")) {
            return false;
        }

        if (s.toCharArray()[0] == '_') { // this check should not be -> this is
                                            // a bug
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Corresponding instrumented bytecode

```
 public static boolean isValidName(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
       3: iconst_1
       4: iadd
       5: bipush        16
       7: irem
       8: putstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      11: getstatic     #40                 // Field instrumentation_static_stack:[Lme/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem;
      14: getstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      17: aaload
      18: astore_2
      19: aload_2
      20: bipush        -1
      22: ldc           #113                // String isValidName_Ljava_lang_String__Z
      24: invokevirtual #48                 // Method me/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem.init:(ILjava/lang/String;)V
      27: aload_0
      28: ldc           #115                // String [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
      30: invokevirtual #118                // Method java/lang/String.matches:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
      33: ifne          56
      36: iconst_0
      37: aload_2
      38: invokevirtual #110                // Method me/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem.clear:()V
      41: getstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      44: iconst_1
      45: isub
      46: bipush        16
      48: iadd
      49: bipush        16
      51: irem
      52: putstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      55: ireturn
      56: aload_0
      57: invokevirtual #122                // Method java/lang/String.toCharArray:()[C
      60: iconst_0
      61: caload
      62: bipush        95
      64: if_icmpne     87
      67: iconst_0
      68: aload_2
      69: invokevirtual #110                // Method me/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem.clear:()V
      72: getstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      75: iconst_1
      76: isub
      77: bipush        16
      79: iadd
      80: bipush        16
      82: irem
      83: putstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      86: ireturn
      87: iconst_1
      88: aload_2
      89: invokevirtual #110                // Method me/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem.clear:()V
      92: getstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
      95: iconst_1
      96: isub
      97: bipush        16
      99: iadd
     100: bipush        16
     102: irem
     103: putstatic     #38                 // Field instrumentation_static_stackpointer:I
     106: ireturn
```

This is the exact error thrown:

```
  Unexpected error: Lexer: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    lexer/Lexer.isValidName(Ljava/lang/String;)Z @68: aload_2
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[2]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
    bci: @68
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { integer }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 2604 6010 1070 b300 26b2 0028 b200
    0000010: 2632 4d2c 10ff 1271 b600 302a 1273 b600
    0000020: 769a 0017 032c b600 6eb2 0026 0464 1010
    0000030: 6010 1070 b300 26ac 2ab6 007a 0334 105f
    0000040: a000 1703 2cb6 006e b200 2604 6410 1060
    0000050: 1010 70b3 0026 ac04 2cb6 006e b200 2604
    0000060: 6410 1060 1010 70b3 0026 ac            
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@56)
    same_frame(@87)
```

I use the asm library to instrument the methods and used `this.method.visitLocalVariable("localstackref", "[Lme/instrumentor/InstrumentStackElem;",null, bl, el,this.stackelementindex);` to add the local variable. `stackelementindex` in this case was 2.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated bytecode is correct, except for the fact that you forgot to update the stackmap table.

For reference, here's pseudocode for what your generated bytecode does.

```
instrumentation_static_stackpointer = (instrumentation_static_stackpointer + 1) % 16
a2 = instrumentation_static_stack[instrumentation_static_stackpointer]
a2.init(-1, "isValidName_Ljava_lang_String__Z")
if (!s.matches("[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*")) goto L56
a2.clear()
instrumentation_static_stackpointer = (instrumentation_static_stackpointer - 1 + 16) % 16
return 0

L56:
if (s.toCharArray()[0] != 95) goto L87
a2.clear()
instrumentation_static_stackpointer = (instrumentation_static_stackpointer - 1 + 16) % 16
return 0

L87:
instrumentation_static_stackpointer = (instrumentation_static_stackpointer - 1 + 16) % 16
return 1
```

The problem is that in bytecode version 51.0+, which is presumably what you are using, it is mandatory to include type information about the bytecode variables as well in the `StackMapTable` attribute. However you did not update this to include the type for your new variable `a2`. The stack map table is only consulted whenever there is a jump or jump target. So when it gets to L56, it consults the table to see what the incoming types are, and the table says that the only variable is `s` with type `String`. Then it gets to `a2.clear()`, sees that you are using a variable which didn't exist in the stack map table, and fails verification.

Comment: Okay, thank you! How do I add the variable to the `StackMapTable`? I hoped that `visitLocalVariable` would do this for me...

Comment: You surely want to use the flag [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) to let the `ClassWriter` do that for you…